# VISUAL STUDIO/POWERSHELL ERROR

Tags: c, visual-studio, powershell

Cuando creo un nuevo archivo en visual studio y desarrollo codigo al compilar me marca ese error en el nombre del archivo en C. Y me pasa con cualquier archivo que ejecute.

[image: Unexpected token 'helloworld' in expression or statement.]

El codigo que probe es solo un printf con "hola mundo"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambia el tipo de terminal a un **command prompt**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Christian lo intenté pero no funcionó

Comment: Te recomendaria que le colocaras la extensión `.exe` para que windows lo reconozca como un ejecutable. Y no seria `C\"helloworld"`, sino `.\helloworld`.

Comment: @Pablochaches Como coloco esa extension? soy nuevito usando visualstudio

Comment: No en visual studio, sino al archivo. Que se llame `helloworld.exe` en lugar de solo `helloworld`.